# Rails 3 issue with custom named resourceful route after update from rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing

In the rails 2 version of my app I have this resource defined

```
map.resources :albums, :as => 'music', :has_many => :reviews
```

This gave me some standard routes:

```
album GET    /music/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"show"}
new_album GET    /music/new(.:format) {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"new"}
```

I also have a polymorphic association set up as follows:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, :as => :reviewable
end


class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reviewable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

This meant I could create a link to my album resource through my review by using a polymorphic path

```
<%= review.reviewable.title, polymorphic_path(review.reviewable) %>
```

However, since upgrading to rails 3 I've changed my routes file to in order to comply with the new router:

```
resources :music, :controller => 'albums' do
  resources :reviews
end
```

And although cleaner it breaks my polymorphic link, i.e.

```
<%= review.reviewable.title, polymorphic_path(review.reviewable) %>
```

I end up with the following error message

```
undefined method `album_path'
```

If I look in my rails 3 generated routes with "rake routes" i see

```
music GET    /music/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"albums"}
```

which is different to what was there before in the rails 2, i.e.

```
album GET    /music/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"show"}
```

So my guess is that this is what's breaking things.

I'm a little unsure though as how to fix it without reverting back to the rails 2 routes which will be depreciated with rails 3.1. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was easy to fix. All I had to do was:

```
resources :albums, :path => 'music' do
  resources :reviews
end
```